# how to create SVG Elements (polylines) faster

Tags: javascript, performance, svg, dom

I'm rendering images as SVG elements, where each pixel is a polyline hexagon.

Each polyline element holds 12 values (see coordinate example below)

Having 50.000 - 100.000 polyline elements makes things slow.

```
function appendPixelsToSVG(svgElement, coordinates) {
  const xmlns = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
  for (let i = 0; i < coordinates.length; ++i) {
    const new_path = document.createElementNS(xmlns, 'polyline');
    new_path.setAttributeNS(null, 'points', coordinates[i]);
    new_path.setAttributeNS(null, 'opacity', 1.0);
    new_path.setAttributeNS(null, 'fill', '#000000');
    svgElement.appendChild(new_path);
  }
}
```

example of coordinate data format:

```
0: " -18.530797027515483, 67.75  -17.37609648913623, 67.75  -16.798746219946604, 68.75  -17.37609648913623, 69.75  -18.530797027515483, 69.75  -19.10814729670511, 68.75 "
1: " -9.870542989671096, 67.75  -8.715842451291843, 67.75  -8.138492182102217, 68.75  -8.715842451291843, 69.75  -9.870542989671096, 69.75  -10.447893258860722, 68.75 "
2: " -1.2102889518267106, 67.75  -0.05558841344745824, 67.75  0.5217618557421679, 68.75  -0.05558841344745824, 69.75  -1.2102889518267106, 69.75  -1.7876392210163368, 68.75 "
3: " 7.449965086017679, 67.75  8.604665624396931, 67.75  9.182015893586557, 68.75  8.604665624396931, 69.75  7.449965086017679, 69.75  6.872614816828053, 68.75 "
4: " 16.110219123862066, 67.75  17.26491966224132, 67.75  17.842269931430945, 68.75  17.26491966224132, 69.75  16.110219123862066, 69.75  15.53286885467244, 68.75 "
5: " 24.770473161706448, 67.75  25.9251737000857, 67.75  26.502523969275327, 68.75  25.9251737000857,
```

My idea was to just put all coordinates into the same polyline element, but that screws up my image because the polyline element obviously doesn't know which coordinates belong together and which not.

As alredy mentioned: **always 12 elements belong together**.

So is there maybe a trick to get this working? creating only one polyline element is actually really fast.

Comment: Maybe a job for Canvas?

Comment: use a single `<path />` with `d="M" + coordinates.join("zM") + "z"`

Comment: @Thomas this is exactly what i was looking for. could you write this down as an actual answer so i can mark it as solved? thanks!

Comment: Wait, 50000 such hexagons? take a look at [<pattern>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/pattern). Create a single hexagon and tesselate it over an entire area. And these coordinates have way more precision than they need. 2-3 decimal places should be fine.

Comment: I can see two strategies, depending on the ultimate purpose: if you need the serialized XML, consider constructing that without ever rendering it. If the purpose is rendering only, you should investigate whether rounding the numbers with `Number.toFixed()` prior to setting the attribute improves performance. And you should definitely leave out the `opacity="1.0"` and  `fill="#000000"` (they are the default anyway), or at least move them either to a parent element or to a stylesheet to avoid repeated parsing.

Comment: @ccprog rendering and correctness of the numbers are very important. using path like Thomas suggested works very well & really fast.

Comment: Precision might be important, but I can't imagine any medium that is able to represent 16 significant digits. Taking antialiasing into account, anything smaller than at most two decimals below the smallest dot the medium is able to reproduce does not make any difference, while parsing the digits from string still takes time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using path instead of polylines works:

```
new_path.setAttributeNS(null, 'd', `M${coordinates.join('zM')}z`);
```